# form validation in javascript and jquery for security

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, html-sanitizing

I'm creating a form that posts some address data that converts this into a lat and long and does some cool stuff on a map.

**My question is:**

If this is all done in JavaScript, do I still need to apply some sort of server side validation to prevent improper use?

Thinking mostly about malicious use here rather than making sure it's the correct data.

When trying to prevent any sort of improper use with the post and get, is there anything I should do with this or is the main concern with people trying to post dodgy data to a database or emailing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should validate both on the client and the server, the client validation will allow you to avoid making unneeded calls to the server.

However, whatever you do on the client will end up in a network call so a "hacker" can make the call he wants(say with postman) thus, avoiding whatever validation you did on client side.

Comment: thanks, could you give me an example of this? The trouble I'm having is if I'm not passing anything to the server I don't get at what point I'd validate things?